# Server 2008 VS Server 2008 R2 for new web and DB servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm setting up 1 IIS web server and 1 SQL Server 2008 server in a colo facility.  I'm wondering if Server 2008 or Server 2008 R2 would be be better to use on these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would specify the latest version (including service pack) unless I had good reason not to.

Good reasons could include:

- The provider doesn't yet support the latest version (provider includes whomever will provider operational support).
- The product has only been tested with an earlier version (and there is no time to update the testing)
- You need something that isn't in the later version (e.g. hardware with only 32bit driver support).

Starting with an older version is another form of technical debt, so only take it on if you need to. But be open about the possibility of needing to.

Comment: I was kind of leaning towards that anyway, but thought it would be good to good some reassurance, thanks for the insights!